# Is Qatar's carry-on allowance 20" maximum height (and no combined length)? Is it strictly enforced?

Tags: hand-luggage, qatar-airways, qatar

Qatar's carry-on baggage allowance is:

> Maximum dimensions for each piece of hand baggage are 50x37x25cm
>   (20x15x10in);

[Almost all other airlines](https://upgradedpoints.com/carry-on-luggage-size-chart) (updated May 15, 2019) have at least 21.5" height for carry-on luggage. Also, if it were a combined measurement, this wouldn't be a problem, but it seems like the maximum height is fixed at 20".

Why is Qatar's maximum height for carry-on luggage only 20"? Do passengers with carry-on bags that are 21" have to have them checked in? Anyone have experience with Qatar?